# How can I update my datasource and animate the changes with RxSwift in my tableview?

Tags: uitableview, reload, rx-swift

Datasource is updating, but the changes are not being displayed in the Tableview.

I am experimenting with Friends, Users, & Users Request tableview with 3 sections. When a user has a request from a user, he or she appears under the request section. However, when the user clicks "accept" the console is reading it's hitting the firebase server, but the changes that that request was actually made is not registering and the request remains in the section until you reload the view. I have tried forcing a tableview to reload, but to no avail.

```
struct SectionOfuserRxx {
    var header: String
    var items: [Item]        
}

extension SectionOfuserRxx: IdentifiableType {    

}

extension SectionOfuserRxx: AnimatableSectionModelType {

   // typealias Item = user

    typealias Identity = String

    ////

    typealias Item = user

    init(original: SectionOfuserRxx, items: [Item]) {
        self = original
        self.items = items
    }

    var identity: String {
        return header
    }

}
// Above viewDidLoad
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
// 

//Inside viewDidLoad

   let dataSource =  RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource<SectionOfuserRxx>(
            configureCell: { dataSource, tableView, indexPath, item in

                       switch (indexPath.section) {

                            case 2:

                                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as? userCell
                                let userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn = item.userImageURL

                                            let userNameTagFirebaseReturn = item.nametag
                                            let userNameFirebaseReturn = item.username

                                            let imageURL = userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn

                                            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: imageURL!)!, cacheKey: userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn)

                                            cell?.userProfileImage.kf.setImage(with: resource)
                                  cell?.usernameLbl.text = userNameFirebaseReturn
                                            cell?.userNameTagLbl.text = "| " + userNameTagFirebaseReturn!
                                 cell!.setFunction {

                                            cell!.button.isEnabled = true
                                            let id =  item.userUID

                                            FriendSystem.system.sendRequestToUser(id!)

                        }
                                return cell!
                            case 1:
                                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendsCell", for: indexPath) as? friendsCell
 cell!.buttons.isEnabled = true
                                            cell!.buttons.setTitle("Remove", for: UIControl.State())

                                         //   print("Friend Count: \(item.count)");



                                                print(" INDEXING ROW FOR FRIENDS: \(indexPath.row)")
                                            let userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn = item.userImageURL ?? ""

                                            let userNameTagFirebaseReturn = item.nametag ?? ""
                                            let userNameFirebaseReturn = item.username ?? ""


                                            let imageURL = userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn

                                         //   self.urlContentArray.append(imageURL)


                                            if imageURL != "" {
                                                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: imageURL)!, cacheKey: userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn)

                                                cell?.userProfileImage.kf.setImage(with: resource)


                                            } else {


                                                cell?.userProfileImage.image = UIImage(named: "heartfilled")
                                            }

                                 cell?.usernameLbl.text = userNameFirebaseReturn

                                cell?.userNameTagLbl.text = userNameTagFirebaseReturn;
                                 cell!.setFunction {
                                                cell!.buttons.isEnabled = true
                                                let id = item.userUID
                                               // FriendSystem.system.friendList.remove(at: indexPath.row)

                                                FriendSystem.system.removeFriend(id!)

                }
                                return cell!
                            case 0:
                                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "requestCell", for: indexPath) as? requestCell
                                    cell!.button.isEnabled = true
                                           // cell!.button.setTitle("Accept", for: UIControl.State())


                                            let userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn = item.userImageURL

                                            let userNameTagFirebaseReturn = item.nametag
                                            let userNameFirebaseReturn = item.username

                                            let imageURL = userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn

                                           // self.urlContentArray.append(imageURL)



                                             //   guard imageURL != nil && imageURL != "" else {return}


                                                if imageURL != nil && userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn != nil && userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn != "" && imageURL != "" {
                                             let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: imageURL!)!, cacheKey: userProfileImageURLFirebaseReturn)


                                                    cell?.userProfileImage.kf.setImage(with: resource)
                                                    cell?.usernameLbl.text = userNameFirebaseReturn
                                                    cell?.userNameTagLbl.text = userNameTagFirebaseReturn

                                                };
                                           // cell?.userProfileImage.kf.setImage(with: resource)
                                            cell?.usernameLbl.text = userNameFirebaseReturn
                                            cell?.userNameTagLbl.text = userNameTagFirebaseReturn

                                            //cell?.button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.3354814752, blue: 0.289293822, alpha: 1)


                                            cell!.setFunction {

                                                cell!.button.isEnabled = true


                                                let id = item.userUID
                                                    FriendSystem.system.acceptFriendRequest(id!)
                                            }
                                return cell!
                            default:
                                return UITableViewCell();

                }},
            titleForHeaderInSection: { dataSource, index in
                return dataSource.sectionModels[index].header
        });

        dataSource.animationConfiguration = AnimationConfiguration(insertAnimation: .fade, reloadAnimation: .fade, deleteAnimation: .fade);
```

******* THIS IS HOW THE ARRAY IS BEING UPDATED AND BEING PULLED IN WITH A FIREBASE OBSERVER IN THE VIEWDIDLOAD *******

var requestList = user

```
var requestListUser = [String]()
/** Adds a friend request observer. The completion function will run every time this list changes, allowing you
 to update your UI. */
func addRequestObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {




    let ref =  USER_REF.child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("requests");

    ref.keepSynced(true);

    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid) != nil else { return }
        self.requestList.removeAll()
        self.requestListUser.removeAll()
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

            let id = child.key

            FriendSystem.system.getCurrentUser({ (userDataReturned) in

                if userDataReturned.email != nil && userDataReturned.userImageURL != nil &&
                    userDataReturned.nametag != nil &&
                    userDataReturned.username != nil &&
                    userDataReturned.userUID != nil {

                    self.requestListUser.append(id);
                    self.getUser(id, completion: { (user) in
                        self.requestList.append(user)
                        update()
                    });

                } else {
                    print("User request account had an account not completely populated")
                }

            })
            // self.requestListUser.append(id)
            //                self.getUser(id, completion: { (user) in
            //                    self.requestList.append(user)
            //                    update()
            //                })
        }
        // If there are no children, run completion here instead
        if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
            update()
        }
    })
}
```

**** IN VIEWDIDLOAD. ****

//THIS adds an observer and fills the userList array
FriendSystem.system.addUserObserver {

}

Comment: The code you posted isn't the problem. In order for the table view to update, the Observable it is observing must actually emit a new array. Show us how you are updating your data source and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @DanielT. Here is how the array is being updated